# How to convert list of floats into strings to append to another list

Tags: python-3.x, wing-ide

Everywhere on the web I can find how to convert strings to integers but the opposite does not seem to be working. With this error (argument 2 to map() must support iteration)

My integers:
 -0.707106781187
-1.0
-0.408248290464
0.0

The relevant parts of my code:

```
def calculateZscore(inFileName, outFileName):
    inputFile = open(inFileName,"r")  
    txtfile = open(outFileName, 'w')

for line in inputFile:
  newList = line.strip().split(',')
  obsExp = newList[-2:]
  obsExp = list(map(int, obsExp))
  obs = obsExp[0]
  exp = obsExp[1]
  zScore = (obs - exp) / math.sqrt(exp)
  zScore = list(map(str, zScore))    
  print zScore

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Comment: hmmm true they are floats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `zScore` will be a float. As your error message suggests, the second argument to `map()` must be an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) (such as a `list`, `str` or `tuple`).

Unless I am missing something, `zScore` is always a single value, so you could probably get away with simply:

```
str(zScore)
```

I am not sure how you intend to use `zScore` later in your program, but from what you have in your example I don't see any advantage to using `map`, unless you need to apply `str` to a list or tuple of values.

However, if you just want your current code to stop raising the error in question, then try replacing this:

```
zScore = list(map(str, zScore))
```

with this:

```
zScore = map(str, [zScore])
```

Also, [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) will return an iterator, so no need to call `list()` on the result unless you need to get all the values at once.